# Setup git-dir and git-work-tree on TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, user-interface, environment-variables, tortoisegit

I am trying to understand if I can setup *--git-dir* and *--git-work-tree* params in TortoiseGIT. I have the working directory in a storage unit, and I can't keep *.git* directory there because its backup is done once a day and there would be a lot of wasted space, so I must put my *.git* dirs in another place.

This works if I use GIT console and I do all the things described on [progit](http://progit.org/2010/04/11/environment.html), to setup GIT_DIR environment variable.

Is there any way I can do this with TortoiseGIT? I hoped that there were a file like *.gitignore* to tell git where to find *.git* dir, but I got nothing so far.

If you know other GUIs that allow to do this it will be useful.

Any help appreciated,
thanks, Michele

PS: I cannot store my projects in another place and I'd prefer to not to merge both ways everytime I work on projects because I don't know if someone else worked there. So GIT_DIR solution is the best thing I've got so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by doing the following :

- move your .git folder elsewhere (PATH_TO_A_NEW_GIT_FOLDER)
- run the following command **in your source folder**

git init --separate-git-dir="PATH_TO_A_NEW_GIT_FOLDER"

This will put a .git file in your source folder that will point on this new folder.

- you're done, TortoiseGit will use your new git folder as if this one is in your source folder

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with TortiseGit.  The command worked well, created a repo that Git bash can see. But TortiseGit's Windows Explorer integration doesn't seem to notice it.

Comment: I've edited my answer but you're right. The right click work with all of it's commands, but not the Explorer integration (icons).

Comment: I've just updated from Tortoise Git 2.0 to 2.1 and it's working now (even the icons)

Comment: When you first clone your .git repo don't include any submodules. This will cause errors in TortoiseGit after the new gitdir. Do Gerard's steps above. Afterwards sync your submodules.

Answer (score 0):

It needed a little extra work, but finally I got it working.
I use both T´Git in Explorer *and* Git in Msys2 *plus* `--separate-git-dir`.
T´Git: 2.15.0 + git-2.42.0.windows
Msys2-Git: 2.42.0

1. `git init --separate-git-dir=path/to/gitdir foo` in MSys2 bash
   You get a workdir `foo/` with file `./foo/.git` containing something like:
   **`gitdir: /c/path/to/gitdir`**
2. Change this to:
   **`gitdir: c:/path/to/gitdir`**
   (it also works with relative paths)
3. enjoy

T´Git is able to handle the forward-slashes while Msys2-Git is accepting the **`C:/..`** path syntax.
Now you can use T´Git via explorer and also Git via Msys2-Bash.

BTW: I have a bash script `"tgit"`, to open T´Git-Log from current directory.
The important part is like this:

```
main() {
  local tgit_exe=$(cygpath -w PATH_TO_TortoiseGitProc_exe)
  local wrk=$(cygpath -w "${1:-.}")
  \cmd <<<"${tgit_exe} /command:log /path:${wrk}"
}
```

Funny:  As far as I can see, T´Git has a `/path:` option, but nothing like `/git-dir:..`
It also has no method to create a Git-Repo with separated Git-Dir.